# Windows could not start the SQL Server (mssqlserver) service on local computer error 17058

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with virtual machine on the windows 8. There is a SQL Server 2008 on the virtual machine. And in the services; when I try to start the SQL Server service getting an error like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Edit:

The OS of virtual machine is windows server 2008.

Comment: In the system event log, I found this message: "The SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) service terminated with service specific error 17058(0x42A2)

Comment: can you check if your SQL Errorlog file has become read only? I just had this 2 weeks ago and still looking for a root cause. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG. Btw, this is based on the assumtion that infact your SQL Server was running happily and nobody or nothing has changed anything to the system. Because the error message itself is kind of general..;-)

Comment: @EdwardDortland I couldn't find SQl Errorlog in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.n\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG" or any other destination.

Comment: It might be that I've given you the wrong location. Or it might be the very reason for your error ;-) Anyway, read this to check your error log file location: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varund/archive/2009/03/21/how-to-verify-path-for-sql-server-error-log-files.aspx?Redirected=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CHeck for another error in the event log that is time-correlated to this one. Basically - this one is from the service manager. The SQL Server service should have written another error (either into th event log or the errorlog) that contains the internal error that happened. THis error is generic from the serivce manager and as such totally irrelevant to debugging. It also is well known - google for "Sql server 17058" finds tons of references.

It seems to be a permission error:

http://www.it-sideways.com/2012/11/mssql-startup-error-code-17058.html

points to

"Could not open error log file ''. Operating system error = 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.)."

which would be an operating system level configuration or insallation issue.

Comment: yes it is a permission error. It was about hyper-v management virtual drive configuration. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could check that you have all paths configured correctly in this service properties in SQL Server Configuration Manager or Services. This is tab called Startup parameters.